# Loading page into div causes page's javascript to not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading a page into a div by

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#div").load("page.php");
});
</script>
```

The page loads but the javascript that I have in page.php does not load.
This is what I have:

```
<script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
$(function() {
    $("#date").datePicker(); 
}); 
</script>
```

When I load page.php outside of the div (as in its own tab/window), the page works perfectly. (The above is copy-pasta from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker).

What is the cause and how can I solve it?

Comment: Whats with scripts wrapped in scripts?  And the link tags inside a script tag?

Comment: Is it because you have multiple definitions of jquery?

Comment: Copy-pasta from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Does Firebug or your web browser developer tool tell you anything?

Comment: Why are you loading the jquery and jqueryui inside the loaded content too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your scripts are never loaded. They are stripped out during load.

> (The above is copy-pasta from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I'm going to assume that you mean you are copying the *entirety* of that sample's source, which looks roughly like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Snipped for brevity: A bunch of script and link elements-->
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

So you're taking this document using [jQuery's load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and placing it inside a div:

```
$("#div").load("page.php");
```

## Load won't cooperate here

According to the [docs on .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

In my own experience, this normally means that `.load()` will only return content from inside the body element, without the body element itself. In other words, from the above sample, this is the only HTML actually being loaded:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

You should use your browser's developer tools (F12) to put a breakpoint in the script and find out what actually gets loaded.

## How do you do this properly?

There's two parts to it.

### Part 1: Move resources outside the `<head>` element

The Datepicker code sample contains a few resources in the `<head>`. You're going to have to place these elsewhere.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

#### The link elements

These can't be loaded up by the page you're loading. Place those inside the `<head>` element of the parent page you're trying to load this other one into.

#### The script elements

These will be loaded up when you load the document, too, as long as:

- You place them within the `<body>` element of the document you're loading, and
- [You adhere to this section in the jQuery .load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) to make sure you load in the script elements correctly.

However, it's only jQuery and jQuery UI, which you know you're going to be using. You might as well move these into the parent page's `<head>` element too.

### 2. Place the important bits you're trying to load in the body.

That's these bits:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Place those inside the `<body>` element of the document you're trying to load. Then, provided you [followed that advice about scripts](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution), this will be loaded successfully.

Optionally, include jQuery references in the `<body>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! It is as you stated.

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to change:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#date").datePicker(); 
}); 
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
  $("#date").datePicker(); 
</script>
```

as the `document.ready` event has already fired, which is what `$(function() {` tells it to wait for.  I'm not sure if jquery automatically runs scripts in ajax'ed content, if not, you could try this (not neccessarily safe, make sure you understand the security risks of `eval` if you do this).

```
$("#div").load("page.php", function() {
    $("#div").find("script").each(function(i) {
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Note:  this will run something like:

```
<script>
  $("#date").datePicker(); 
</script>
```

But NOT something like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#date").datePicker(); 
}); 
</script>
```

As, again, the second waits for the `document.ready` event, which has already fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$(document).ready()` aka `$(function)` will not execute when you load the document with `load`.
You can try to trigger it manually in the `complete` callback of `load`, or you can name the function you pass to `$` and call it.